# React Remix and Clerk authentication

Tags: reactjs, remix, clerk

I followed the React Remix / Clerk authentication tutorial very closely and it seems that no matter what I do, I get a 401 Not Authorized page, as soon as I plug the loader function in route.jsx (I am using JS, not TypeScript):

```
import {
  Links,
  LiveReload,
  Meta,
  Outlet,
  Scripts,
  ScrollRestoration,
} from "@remix-run/react";

import {rootAuthLoader} from '@clerk/remix/ssr.server'
import { ClerkApp, ClerkCatchBoundary } from "@clerk/remix";

export const loader = args => {
  return rootAuthLoader(
    args,
    ({ request }) => {
      const { userId, sessionId, getToken } = request.auth;
      console.log("Root loader auth:", { userId, sessionId, getToken });
      return { message: `Hello from the root loader :)` };
    },
    { loadUser: true }
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>
        <Outlet />
        <ScrollRestoration />
        <Scripts />
        <LiveReload />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

export default ClerkApp(App);

export const CatchBoundary = ClerkCatchBoundary();
```

Any ideas?

I have setup the account, copied the environment keys to .env and they are getting picked up by Remix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the new Remix [V2 Error Boundaries](https://remix.run/docs/en/main/route/meta-v2) then you likely need to use the code in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/clerkinc/javascript/issues/965#issuecomment-1516836522) which uses the ErrorBoundary to handle what Clerk is expecting to be handled in the old CatchBoundary.

I just went through the setup and it worked out.

The other issue I had was the wrong env variable names. I copied the Next.js version instead of the ones for Remix. You can get them from the Home page on the Clerk dashboard for your account.

Comment: Do you know where to add the github code snippet?

Comment: It is a custom component. Therefore you could put it with your other components. Then import it to the root.tsx file and return it from the ErrorBoundary exported function in that file.